# How can I move my deploy key into vagrant?

Tags: vagrant

I'd like to move a an ssh key into vagrant and put them in `~/.ssh`, what's the easiest way of doing that? I have the following in my Vagrant file:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "conf.d", "/svr/conf.d"
config.vm.provision :shell, 
:inline => "ls -l /svr/conf.d/.ssh"
```

> total 4
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 1670 Mar 26 08:19 id_rsa.mediapop

```
config.vm.provision :shell, 
:inline => "cp /svr/conf.d/.ssh/id_rsa.mediapop /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa"
config.vm.provision :shell, 
:inline => "ls -l /home/ubuntu/.ssh"
```

> total 4
>   -rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Mar 22 08:56 authorized_keys
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   1670 Mar 26 08:59 id_rsa

but then when I do `vagrant ssh -c "ls -l ~/.ssh"` I get:

```
$ vagrant ssh -c "ls -l ~/.ssh"
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 409 Mar 20 04:47 authorized_keys
```

So vagrant is overwriting my `.ssh` directory.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I put my SSH file in `conf.d/.ssh/id_rsa.medipop` and then did:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "conf.d", "/svr/conf.d"
config.vm.provision :shell, 
:inline => "cp /svr/conf.d/.ssh/id_rsa.mediapop /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

Which worked splendidly once I realised the vagrant user is `vagrant` not `ubuntu` (which is why I was confused in my question as to why my ssh key seemed to disappear).

Comment: This is the way on windows, where agent forwarding doesn't work.

Comment: works but get this error, ==> default: stdin: is not a tty
 also permissions change and had to be reset, will running with sudo off fix?

Answer (score 12):

What about [SSH Agent Forwarding?](https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-agent-forwarding)

Make sure your SSH key works locally first then
add `config.ssh.forward_agent = true` to your `Vagrantfile` to pass through.

Vagrant details here: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html

Comment: I'm weary about doing that since I'm planning on distributing the vagrant box to our designers who would probably look at me funny if I started referring to keychains as computer things. :) Thanks though!

Comment: In that case I'd either build my own box with [VeeWee](https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee) and distribute it as a package including `config.ssh.private_key_path` or do something terrible like have the ssh key in the project folder with the Vagrantfile. It's got to be distributed somehow in the use case, so pick your evil!

Comment: This is pretty much the same question: http://superuser.com/a/570775/210384

Answer (score 5):

You can use Ruby's core File module, like so:

```
  config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    ssh_pub_key = File.readlines("#{Dir.home}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub").first.strip
    s.inline = <<-SHELL
      echo #{ssh_pub_key} >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
      echo #{ssh_pub_key} >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
    SHELL
  end
```

I'm really surprised that Vagrant doesn't provide this by default!

Comment: I would recommend to also add quotes around `echo` arguments:  `echo "#{ssh_pub_key}" >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys` and `echo "#{ssh_pub_key}" >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`. This will also work if a public SSH key contains special characters (e.g. `(`).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Vagrant Shell Provisioner](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html), you'd add this to your Vagrantfile.

However, depending on what you're trying to achieve, it's probably better to use the supplied ssh key to access Vagrant.

To generate a quick config file to be added to your `~/.ssh/config`, including an identity file line run `$ vagrant ssh-config`. You could then `$ ssh you-vagrant-box` rather than `$ vagrant ssh`.

Comment: Ah this is not for SSH'ing into my box, this is to give vagrant access to my git repos. So I need to move a file from my host into ~/.ssh/

Comment: That is more clear! In your edit above are you sure that `~/` and `/home/ubuntu` are the same location? Vagrant's default homedir is `/home/vagrant`.

Comment: Don't forget that your Vagrantfile is fully interpreted ruby, so you could do something like:  
`git_ssh_key = File.read('/svr/conf.d/.ssh/id_rsa.mediapop');  
config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "cat >>/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rda.mediapop <<EOF #{git_ssh_key} EOF"`  
You may run into permissions issues reading the ssh key though.

Comment: I have managed to copy the file into `~/.ssh` using a synced folder and `cp`, but it seems like vagrant overwrites it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

To move both private and public keys the following will work:

```
config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
  ssh_prv_key = File.read("#{Dir.home}/.ssh/id_rsa")
  ssh_pub_key = File.readlines("#{Dir.home}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub").first.strip
  s.inline = <<-SHELL
    echo Provisioning public ssh key...
    [ -e /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ] && rm /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
    touch /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
    echo "#{ssh_pub_key}" >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

    echo Provisioning private ssh key...
    [ -e /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa ] && rm /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa
    touch /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa
    echo "#{ssh_prv_key}" >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa

    echo Provisioning of ssh keys completed [Success].
  SHELL
end
```